# Mongoose: Deleting a value from an array in an object from a document

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I would like to know how I would go about doing this.

I have a webshop that I'm working on for school. This is the category array I would like to remove from the object (the one inside "products"):

[image: Updated picture for clarity]

My code is as follows:

```
        webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.webshop, {
          categories: { $pull: { products: productId } },
        });
```

This does not work. It does not remove the product that I have specified from the frontend (I made sure that it was sent with the request, it is)

How would I go about removing said value from the array?

I have also tried doing this:

```
        webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.webshop, {
          $pull: { categories: { products: productId } },
        });
```

But to no avail.

Full code of function:

```
const productId = req.body.productId;
productsCollection
  .deleteOne({ _id: productId })
  .then(() =>
    webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.webshop, {
      $pull: { products: productId },
    })
  )
  .then(() => {
    webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.webshop,
      {
        $pull: {
          "categories.$[category].products": productId,
        },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "category.products": productId,
          },
        ],
      }
    );
  })
  .then(() => {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: "Product deleted successfully" });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "Something went wrong. Please try again later" });
  });
```

**UPDATE:** I fixed it

```
const productId = req.body.productId;
await productsCollection.deleteOne({ _id: productId });
await webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.webshop, {
  $pull: { products: productId },
});
await webshopCollection
  .findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.webshop,
    {
      $pull: {
        "categories.$[category].products": productId,
      },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "category.products": productId,
        },
      ],
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: "Product and references deleted successfully" });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: error });
  });
```

It definitely had something to do with all the ".then" promises. I swapped everything to "awaits", and it seemed to work :)

Hope this helps someone randomly coming the same problem as me. You never know.

Comment: Make sure you are comparing same datatype(i.e. not comparing ObjectId with string)

Comment: It is the same type. I updated the picture to more clearly show you what value I'm after. It's not the "objectID". The objectID is the ID of the whole category, not the array string/value I'm after, which is the one in the "products" array.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is invalid. The second argument (object) of `update` must be with the update operator (with `$` prefix) for the key.

**Revised**

For your second query, it will remove the `element` from the `categories` array but not the element in the `products` array.

You should use [`$[<identifier>]` positional filtered operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in this case.

```
webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.webshop,
{
  $pull: {
    "categories.$[category].products": productId
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "category.products": productId
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nkEUPrRR3Jd)

Comment: I'm sorry but "_id" is the ID of the whole category itself. That's not what I'm trying to remove. I'm trying to remove the string in the "products" array. My picture is misleading. I probably should not have included the last line of the document.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, apologized for that. I revised my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually using it in conjuction with the "delete product" function I have. Does that mean I should leave the second query out? I want to delete the product from the from both the products array in the collection, but also from the products array inside the categories object.

I have updated the post with my full code for that.

Comment: It still doesn't want to delete the product from inside the categories object :(

Comment: As mentioned, your first query with `{ categories: { $pull: { products: productId } }` will not be executed as it is incorrect syntax. I believe your full code should be work correctly, by removing the product from product collection, after success callback to remove the item from other collection. But why do you need to `webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate` twice, one with products array and another with `categories.products` array. As it is the same collection and document, you should able to make it in single query [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GFLpBza_qgF)

Comment: Not a Mongoose developer, but I also suspect that your second update query is not running as you didn't supply the callback. The second `then` callback should be placed after as this: `webshopCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(...).then(...)`

Comment: I did a quick console.log to see if it reached the second update query. It did. It still doesn't wanna remove it from the array in the object. I really don't get it. How would I go about turning the 2 queries into 1? I don't think it's going to help with anything, but maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256223/discussion-between-badatcoding-and-yong-shun).